# переведите пожалувста на с++

Tags: c++

```
x1, y1, x2, y2, a = map(float,input().split())
x = (x1 + x2 * a) / (a + 1)
y = (y1 + y2 * a) / (a + 1)
print("%.2f %.2f" %(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x1, y1, x2, y2, a, x, y;
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &a)
x = (x1 + x2 * a) / (a + 1);
y = (y1 + y2 * a) / (a + 1);
printf("%.2f %.2f", x, y);
```